# How to get entries to match xAxis values MP line chart, Android

Tags: android, linechart

I am struggling to get a line chart correctly. I have data in Firestore database and from there I am trying to display temperature readings in a line chart. I am using the latest version of Mp line chart. I am trying to get the temperature values in Celsius to YAxis and the time in HH:mm format to the xAxis. I have tried this in mane ways and googled different ways to do this and I just can't get it right. Either the values don't show at all or the values show but in the wrong spot of the xAxis. also I can't get the yAxis showing correctly. Someone has asked about that here already and the answer was to put the ofset "60, 0 50, 60" but that don't work for me.

For the main issue I am currently trying to use the HourAxisValueFormatter which was instructed in GitHub. There is documentation of it but I can't understand how to get it working. I am new to Android an To Mp library so that is why it is difficult.
Below my activity code and the HourAxisValueFormatter

```
public class TempHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LineChart mChart;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private ArrayList<Integer> tempItemList;
    private ArrayList<Long> timeList, convertedTimes;
    private ArrayList<Date> dateList;
    private Long reference;
    private CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("whtitem");
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp_history);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        tempItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        timeList = new ArrayList<>();
        dateList = new ArrayList<>();
        convertedTimes = new ArrayList<>();

        mChart = findViewById(R.id.tempLineChart);
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
        Marker mv = new Marker(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_marker_view);
        mv.setChartView(mChart);
        mChart.setMarker(mv);
        mChart.setViewPortOffsets(60, 0, 50, 90);
        mChart.setExtraLeftOffset(40);
        retrieveDayDataFromDatabase();

    }

    private void retrieveDayDataFromDatabase() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();
        Calendar cals = Calendar.getInstance();
        cals.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, +1);
        Date tomorrow = cals.getTime();

        collectionReference.whereEqualTo("userId", WhtApi.getInstance()
                .getUserId())
                .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .startAt(currentDate)
                .endAt(tomorrow)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                        dateList.clear();
                        tempItemList.clear();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot whtitems : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            WhtItem whtItem = whtitems.toObject(WhtItem.class);
                            dateList.add(whtItem.getDate());
                            tempItemList.add(whtItem.getTemperature());
                            Log.d("temps", "retrieveDayDataFromDatabase: " + tempItemList);
                        }
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        for (int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++){
                            Date date = dateList.get(i);
                            Long time = Long.valueOf(date.getTime());
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                            //String time = DateFormat.format("HH:mm", dateList.get(i)).toString();
                           /* cal.setTime(dateList.get(i));
                            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            String t = hour +":"+minute+0;
                            Log.d("st", "retrieveDayDataFromDatabase: " + t);
                            DecimalFormatSymbols symbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
                            symbol.setDecimalSeparator(':');
                            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
                            NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
                            format.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
                            format.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
                            float time = 0;
                            try {
                                time = decimalFormat.parse(t).floatValue();
                                Log.d("timef", "retrieveDayDataFromDatabase: " + time);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Float newValue = new Float(format.format(time));
                            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(t).setScale(2);
                            Log.d("decimal", "retrieveDayDataFromDatabase: " + decimal);*/
                            timeList.add(time);
                        }
                        renderDayData();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(TempHistoryActivity.this, "Ei lämpötilakirjauksia vielä", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(TempHistoryActivity.this, "Tapahtui virhe dataa haettaessa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }

    public void renderDayData() {

       Collections.sort(timeList);
        for (int i = 0; i<timeList.size(); i++){
            reference = timeList.get(0);
            Long Xnew = (timeList.get(1)) - reference;
            convertedTimes.add(Xnew);
            Log.d("converted", "renderDayData: "+ convertedTimes);
        }

        LimitLine llXAxis = new LimitLine(10f, "Index 10");
        llXAxis.setLineWidth(4f);
        llXAxis.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        llXAxis.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
        llXAxis.setTextSize(10f);

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new HourAxisValueFormatter(reference));
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(10f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);

        LimitLine ll1 = new LimitLine(33f, "Lämpöraja 33°C");
        ll1.setLineWidth(4f);
        ll1.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        ll1.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
        ll1.setTextSize(15f);
        ll1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getTemperature()));
        leftAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
        leftAxis.addLimitLine(ll1);
        leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(100f);
        leftAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
        leftAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.invalidate();
        setDayData();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDate(){
        ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<dateList.size(); i++){
            String date = DateFormat.format("dd.MM.", dateList.get(i)).toString();
            label.add(date);
        }return label;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTime(){
        ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
        times.add( values[i]);
        }return times;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTemperature(){
        ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i < tempItemList.size(); i++){
            String temp = tempItemList.get(i) + "°C";
            temps.add(temp);
            Log.d("templist", "getTemperature: " + temps);
        }return temps;
    }


    private void setDayData() {
        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.clear();
        for (int i =0 ; i < timeList.size(); i++){
            values.add(new Entry(i, tempItemList.get(i)));
            Log.d("list", "setDayData: " + timeList.get(i));
            Log.d("values", "setData: " + values);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Collections.sort(values, new EntryXComparator());
        }

        LineDataSet set1;
        if (mChart.getData() != null &&
                mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);
            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Lämpötiladata");
            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.enableDashedLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
            set1.enableDashedHighlightLine(10f, 5f, 0f);
            set1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            set1.setCircleColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            set1.setLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(9f);
            set1.setDrawFilled(true);
            set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setFormLineDashEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10f, 5f}, 0f));
            set1.setFormSize(15.f);

            if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
                Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gradient);
                set1.setFillDrawable(drawable);
            } else {
                set1.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
            }
            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            dataSets.add(set1);
            LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
            mChart.setData(data);

            Description description = new Description();
            description.setText("");
            mChart.setDescription(description);
            mChart.invalidate();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.profile:
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(TempHistoryActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.mainpage:
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(TempHistoryActivity.this, MainPageActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.temp_history:
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(TempHistoryActivity.this, TempHistoryActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.pulse_history:
               if (user != null && firebaseAuth!=null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(TempHistoryActivity.this, PulseHistoryActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.time_in_temp_history:
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(TempHistoryActivity.this, TimeTempActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_signout:
                //signout
                if (user != null && firebaseAuth != null) {
                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(TempHistoryActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    //finish();
                }
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
        }



        public class HourAxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter
        {
        private long referenceTimestamp; // minimum timestamp in your data set
    private DateFormat mDataFormat;
    private Date mDate;

    public HourAxisValueFormatter(long referenceTimestamp) {
        this.referenceTimestamp = referenceTimestamp;
        this.mDataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        this.mDate = new Date();
    }
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value){
         // convertedTimestamp = originalTimestamp - referenceTimestamp
         long convertedTimestamp = (int) value;
         // Retrieve original timestamp
         long originalTimestamp = referenceTimestamp + convertedTimestamp;

        // Convert timestamp to hour:minute
        return getHour(originalTimestamp);
    }
         public int getDecimalDigits()
       {
        return 0;
    }

    private String getHour(long timestamp){
        try{
            mDate.setTime(timestamp*1000);
            return mDataFormat.format(mDate);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return "xx";
        }  
        }
        }
```

Here is my output atm
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KMAE.png)

and this is what I am trying to get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ShdQ.png)

I want the xAxis values to be "07:00, 08:00, 09:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00"

Comment: Post an image for current output and another one that you want to implement

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I edited my post to include output now and exmaple of what I am trying to do. Also added what I would like to have as my xAxis values. Int he output now there is 88 celsius as the first value and it should be  11:00 AM, the second should be 1:50 PM and the last 35 should be at 9:00 PM